# Naming: solution, projects, namespaces and assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, naming

I'm working on naming guidelines for solutions, projects, their default namespaces and assemblies (Visual Studio).
Now it looks like that:
For example, we have a company named "Company" and a project named "Project". The project has business logic in separate dll, UI (WPF/WinForms) and a web part. There are names of things listed in the question title:

Solution name: "Project".

Business logic dll project name: "Project", default namespace: "Company.Project", assembly name: "Project".

UI project name: "ProjectUI", default namesapce: "Company.Project.UI" (it can be extended in case of multiple versions of UI, like "Company.Project.UI.WPF"), assembly name "Project" (working because it's not a dll).

Web project name: "ProjectWeb", default namespace: "Company.Project.Web", assembly name: "ProjectWeb" (for web applications).

My questions are: do you have guidelines like that? Is it a good idea to describe thoose things? What you think about my approach?

I'll be glad if you share ways that you use in your work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Microsoft's Namespace Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28VS.71%29.aspx), which are by the way very similar to yours.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's definitely a good idea for everyone to work to standards like these.
The only thing I might add is that if you do projects for other companies/customers you might want to name projects as follows:

`YourCompanyName.CustomerCompanyName.ProjectName.ProjectUI`

Comment: It's a good idea when you work with several customers and projects are not shared between them.